# Find $ker (\phi)$ and $Im(\phi)$ and create the operation $ Q/ ker(\phi)$?

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let us consider the Quartenion group $Q=\{ \pm 1, \pm i, \pm j, \pm k \}$ and $N=\left\langle j \right\rangle$ in $Q$ be a cyclic subgroup. Define $ \phi: Q \to \mathbb{Z}_2 \oplus \mathbb{Z}_2 $ by $ \ \phi(isjt)=([s],[t])$  where $0 \leq s <2$ and $0 \leq t<4$. Then,

Find $ker (\phi)$ and $Im(\phi)$ and create the operation $ Q/ ker(\phi)$ ?

**Answer:**

Let $ (s,t) \in ker (\phi)$, then $ ([s],[t])=(0,0) \Rightarrow s=0, \ t=0.$

Thus $ker(\phi)=\{i,j \}$.

Then $Q/\{i,j \}=K_4 \ \text{klein 4-group} $.

Am I right ?

What is the operation table?

Help me.

Comment: @Surb, so how to find  $ker(\phi)$?

Comment: @Surb, I think $ker (\phi)=\{i, \ j \}$ and $ Q/ker(\phi)=K_4$, klein 4-group.  Am I right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you are right, $Q_8/Z(Q_8)=Q_8/\{1,-1\}\cong C_2\times C_2$ is the Kleinian $4$-group, because every non-trivial element in the quotient has order $2$. So the "table" is clear. I don't see what you do with $N$.